# Call to undefined function mysql_connect() Error using WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site version 4.7.2 sitting on top of PHP 5.6.  I am using PHP Code for Posts plugin to call out a separate activity.  It was working after updating to 4.7 but then somewhere along the line the php code started throwing an error of

> Call to undefined function mysql_connect().

The code I'm using is

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "database-user","database-password") or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database-name");

$url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$postid = url_to_postid( $url );

$query = "SELECT slug FROM all_cases WHERE wp_lesson_post_id = $postid";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$slug = $row['slug'];

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "https://sitename'.$slug.'"
      </script>';

//header("Location: https://sitename/$slug");
```

I also tried PHP Code Snippit and am getting the same error.  Any idea on how to fix this?

***UPDATE***

I'm not very versed with PHP.  So would it look something like this?

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'database-name';
$user = 'user-name';
$pass = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$postid = url_to_postid( $url );

$query = "SELECT slug FROM all_cases WHERE wp_lesson_post_id = $postid";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$slug = $row['slug'];

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "https://sitename'.$slug.'"
      </script>';

header("Location: https://sitename/$slug");
```

Comment: You are absolutely sure you're not on PHP 7?

Comment: anyway, you should not use mysql_* anymore. use mysqli_*  or PDO!

Comment: And while you're at it, when using MySQLi or PDO - make sure to use prepared statements with placeholders for every variable.

Comment: ...looks like a perfect opportunity to update your db-functions!

Comment: On top of that, why did you comment out your `header("Location: ..");` and use JS instead?

Comment: @Qirel My guess: `header` didn't work, because of the error-message.

Comment: This code was supplied by someone else.  I'm not sure why it was commented out.

Comment: Why are you using any of this in WordPress?
You should be using either the WordPress WP_Query or $wpdb or the WPAPI

Comment: While your edit contains a setup for PDO, you never actually use the PDO object. I would suggest reading the SO Docs on PDO starting with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries)